# EF 5 Changing Connection String at Runtime

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, connection-string, entity-framework-5

Ok, I want to recreate a project that I created using EF 4.1 to EF 5.0, simple enough or at least I thought. One of the things in my old project is that I was able to change the database connection string at runtime in EF 4.1:

```
using (var myContext = new MyEntities(ConnectionString))
{

}
```

Easy-peasy but in EF 5.0 you have to do this differently:

```
string connectionString = "data source=LocalHost;initial catalog=MyDatabase;user id=MyUserName;password=MyPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework";

using (var myContext = new MyEntities())
{
         myContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
}
```

Now, this took me a better part of two hours to figure out, so I guess my question is this the proper way of changing the connection string at runtime or not? If it is why did they make this change?

I did find this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364617/ef-5-0-dynamic-connection-string) but it didn't work. I received the error as detailed in the first comment of the first answer by Ladislav Mrnka. I later found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660683/how-to-use-dynamic-connection-string-for-sql-server-ce) which seems to work fine.

## UPDATE

I re-read the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364617/ef-5-0-dynamic-connection-string) I posted and I found another solution, I simply created a partial class:

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) 
    {
          Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should write your edit as an answer and accept it...

Comment: In your answer, the line `Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;` is redundant, because that operation is already done by the base constructor.

Answer (score 6):

Use the context constructor overload that takes the connection string as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with the same name as the Target ContextClass class next to the main class

like this :

```
public CustomerContext( string connectionString) 
    : base(connectionString)
{
}
```

For using :

```
using (var context = new CustomerContext("connectionString"))
{

}
```

Or

```
var customerContext=new CustomerContext("yorConnectionString");

var customer=CustomerContext.customer.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.id==1).FirstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at other link [Setup Entity Framework For Dynamic Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440698/setup-entity-framework-for-dynamic-connection-string).
It says - " you can do it by creating another partial class as the Entities class is declared partial"