# update connection string for dynamic data entities web application

Tags: entity-framework

Using VS 2010, I have created a simple dynamic data entities web application (using the template provided in VS 2010).  It works fine.  However, I want to change the "InitialCatalog" in the model connection string at runtime, via a user selection. I know how to create the new connection string, but I don't know how to update the entity model with the new string.  It is possible to update the model to use the new connection string at runtime, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

on how you are using Entity Framework, this can be done by using the overloaded constructor for context to provide your own connection string.

e.g

```
using(var Context = new Context("my connection string")
{
    // Do some stuff with your context.
}
```

There is a very similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12737289/1341477).