# Manipulating RSSBus for Quickbooks ADO.net ConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, quickbooks

I've written an app using the RSSBus QB ADO.net provider - VS 2010 and .net 4.0.  I'm connecting to QB with the entityframework 6 and using linq.

I'm dynamically changing the connectionstring in order to manipulate the offline cache.  Everything works great.

I've migrated the app to VS 2013 with .net 4.5.  In vs2010/4.0 the QB entity object is of ObjectContext and in vs2013/4.5 the QB entity is of DbContext and I don't have the connectionstring property available.

Is there any other methodology to manipulate the cache settings on the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DbContext does not directly have a Connection property but it does have Database which does contain a Connection object which should allow you to edit the connection string:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

There's another method you can use involving a partial class shown here:

[EF 5 Changing Connection String at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737289/ef-5-changing-connection-string-at-runtime)

Comment: That's it Scott T!  For some reason RSSBus (CDATA) changed the base object.  I was able to change the connectionstring of the Database.Connection.  Thanks.